# Database design json or relation postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, relational-database, jsonb

I am a beginner to databases.
Right now I am working on a Postgresql database design.
I have many entity like :

user->id,name

```
id | name
-----------
 1 | user1
 2 | user2
 3 | user3
```

carsData1->id,price,name,date,catgory,cra_id,uid. {category just enume[p1,p2,p3]},...
Each car in each category must be unique in carsData1 and carsData2 table for each user.

```
id| name  | price | category |    date  | car_id| uid
----------+-------+----------+----------+-------+----
1 | name1 |  245  |    p1    |    2021  | 1001  | 1
2 | name2 |  785  |    p1    |    2021  | 1002  | 1
3 | name3 |  354  |    p3    |    2021  | 1001  | 1
4 | name4 |  897  |    p2    |    2021  | 1003  | 1
5 | name6 |  684  |    p2    |    2021  | 1002  | 1
6 | name7 |  452  |    p3    |    2021  | 1003  | 1
7 | name8 |  125  |    p3    |    2021  | 1001  | 2
8 | name9 |  874  |    p1    |    2021  | 1002  | 3
```

carsData2->id,name,cra_id,uid

```
id| name  | date  | car_id| uid
----------+-------+-------+----
1 | name1 | 2021  | 1001  | 1
2 | name2 | 2021  | 1002  | 2
3 | name3 | 2021  | 1003  | 3
4 | name4 | 2021  | 1001  | 3
5 | name6 | 2021  | 1002  | 1
6 | name7 | 2021  | 1003  | 1
7 | name8 | 2021  | 1001  | 2
8 | name9 | 2021  | 1002  | 3
```

filters -> id,filter,uid,name

```
id| name  | filter              |    date | uid
----------+---------------------+---------+----
1 | name8 |  'string filter8 '  |    2021 | 4
2 | name11|  'string filter11'  |    2021 | 4
3 | name2 |  'string filter2 '  |    2021 | 2
4 | name3 |  'string filter3 '  |    2021 | 2
5 | name1 |  'string filter1 '  |    2021 | 3
6 | name5 |  'string filter5 '  |    2021 | 3
7 | name7 |  'string filter2 '  |    2021 | 3
8 | name6 |  'string filter6 '  |    2021 | 2
```

carsData1,carsData2 and filters tables can be modified by users (CRUD).

- My problem is assigning each filter to each category in the carsData1 table.
- I need each user to be able to apply each filter to a category in the carsData1 or carsData2 table.
- I need to know which cars each filter has been applied to.

My solution:
Create a table instead of carsData1 and carsData2 tables and used jsonb, and create a table to assign filters to each category

carsData:
each user can define 10 cars in data_jsonb.

```
id|category |                      data_jsonb                                                                                            | uid
------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----
1 |   p1    |    [{"name":"name1","car_id":1001,"price":254,"date":"2021"},{"name":"name2","car_id":1002,"price":321,"date":"2021"}]    | 1
2 |   p2    |    [{"name":"name2","car_id":1002,"price":245,"date":"2021"},{"name":"name3","car_id":1003,"price":741,"date":"2019"}]    | 1
3 |   p3    |    [{"name":"name4","car_id":1004,"price":358,"date":"2021"}]                                                             | 1
4 |   CD2   |    [{"name":"name1","car_id":1004},{"name":"name5","car_id":1005}]                                                        | 1
5 |   p1    |    [{"name":"name7","car_id":1007,"price":987,"date":"2021"}]                                                             | 2
6 |   p2    |    [{"name":"name2","car_id":1002,"price":748,"date":"2020"},{"name":"name1","car_id":1001,"price":968,"date":"2019"}]    | 2
7 |   p3    |    [{"name":"name4","car_id":1004,"price":968,"date":"2020"},{"name":"name1","car_id":1001,"price":857,"date":"2021"}]    | 2
8 |   CD2   |    [{"name":"name5","car_id":1005},{"name":"name1","car_id":1001,"price":125,"date":"2021"}]                              | 2
```

assign_filters:

```
carsData_id| filters_id _id
-----------+----------------
      1    |    1
      1    |    2
      3    |    2
      3    |    4
      3    |    6
      5    |    1
      5    |    2
      8    |    5
```

Benefits:

- Each user can only have 4 records in the carData table
- Assigning filters to any user category is easier
- Fetching information is easier.
- Less tables required.

fetching data needed:

```sql
select cd.uid,cd.category,cd.id ,f1."name" ,f1."filter" ,
       (select jsonb_agg(t -> 'car_id')
        from jsonb_array_elements(cd.data_jsonb) as x(t)) as car_id
from carsData cd
left join assign_filters af
on cd.id = af.carsData_id
left join filter f1
on f1.id = af.filters_id
```

```
   id |category      |uid |filter_name |filter           |  car_id    |
------+--------------+----+------------+-----------------+------------+
    3 |p1            |  4 |name8       |'string filter8 '|[1001]      |
    1 |p2            |  4 |name11      |'string filter11'|[1004, 1002]|
    2 |p1            |  2 |name2       |'string filter2 '|[1005]      |
    3 |p1            |  2 |name3       |'string filter3 '|[1006]      |
    3 |p1            |  3 |name1       |'string filter1 '|[1007,1008] |
    1 |p2            |  3 |name5       |'string filter5 '|[1003, 1006]|
    2 |CD2           |  3 |name7       |'string filter2 '|[1005]      |
    3 |p1            |  2 |name6       |'string filter6 '|[1002,1001] |
```

The second solution is to define two pivot table for each carsData1 and carsData2 table.
But I do not know how to fetching data like above for carsData1 table and assign_filters to each category.

**Update:**
If I merge the carData1 and carData2 tables and change an assign_filters table as follows, how can I get the data as follows?

assign_filters:

```
     uid   | filters_id | category
-----------+------------+----------
      1    |    1       |    p1    
      1    |    2       |    p2
      3    |    2       |    p2
      3    |    4       |    p1
      3    |    6       |    CD2
      5    |    1       |    p2
      5    |    2       |    p1
      8    |    5       |    p3
```

Needed results like this:

```
   id |category      |uid |filter_name |filter           |  car_id    |
------+--------------+----+------------+-----------------+------------+
    3 |p1            |  4 |name8       |'string filter8 '|[1001]      |
    1 |p2            |  4 |name11      |'string filter11'|[1004, 1002]|
    2 |p1            |  2 |name2       |'string filter2 '|[1005]      |
    3 |p1            |  2 |name3       |'string filter3 '|[1006]      |
    3 |p1            |  3 |name1       |'string filter1 '|[1007,1008] |
    1 |p2            |  3 |name5       |'string filter5 '|[1003, 1006]|
    2 |CD2           |  3 |name7       |'string filter2 '|[1005]      |
    3 |p1            |  2 |name6       |'string filter6 '|[1002,1001] |
```

Comment: First comment : your tables carsData1 and carsData2 have many columns in common so that the same information is duplicated in both tables (id, name, car_id), so why not merging both tables together ? Then for your first need "My problem is assigning each filter to each category in the carsData1 table" you should create a new table with a foreign key pointing at the carsData1 table and another foreign key pointing at the filters table, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)

Comment: The carsData1 table has many other fields, but the carsData2 table is limited to the fields listed. How do I save the rest of the ddd table fields? According to your method, if each user defines 10 cars for each category and if the user assigns 10 filters to each category, the second table will store 400 records for each user.

Comment: Plain table will be much better than jsonb with array inside it. PostgreSQL has good support for json but it's better if this json is flat. Remember that PostgreSQL don't create statistics for jsonb keys and that you can overcome with indexing keys but you can't do any optimization with json arrays. There will be nested loops everywhere. Updating such data is more complex too. So json arrays are OK while they don't try to mimic a table - use normal table instead.

Comment: As stated by Alex Lu, use plain table instead of json data in your case. You need at least one "cars" table, one "categories" table, one "filters" table. The "cars" table and the "filters " table" need both one column "category" which refers to the "categories" table with a foreign key, so that a filter doesn't refer to a car directly, it refers to a category which also corresponds to a set of cars in the "cars" table.

Comment: How can I get data this way? I updated my questions